# How many exam questions do I have to answer ? Process of elimination

Tags: probability

I have 25 questions to study 
8 of these will be on the exam 
I only have to write about 2

How many exam questions can I " eliminate " from studying

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here.  In what scenario could you "eliminate" even one question from studying?

Comment: not all 25 of the questions will be on the exam . Only 8/25 will . And of those I get to PICK  2 . So if I prepare the questions in advance . I won't need to study some of them .

Comment: Yes! Exactly !!! That's the answer I need

Comment: @Peter I think the fact that you get to choose 2 of the 8 is significant

Comment: So how many would I realistically not have to study

Comment: Knowing 19 out of the 25 guarantees getting 2 right, if 8 questions are presented and the rest may be ignored

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 4):

The "worst case scenario" is when you study for 17 questions, and you got the remaining 8. So if you study 19 questions, then according to the pigeonhole principle, there will be surely 2 questions of the 8 that you will know. If you only want to know 1 question, then you need to learn 18 of them in the worst case.

(Trying to find worst case scenarios is usually not so helpful, because they are hard to define, so I generally don't recommend.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know $k \leq 19$ out of the $25$ questions, then the probability of getting at least two questions you know is given by
$$
1 - \frac{18\cdot\binom{25-k}{7}}{\binom {25}{8}}
$$
If you know $11$, there is approximately a $94\%$ chance of success.  Around $90\%$ if you know $10$.  See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20-%20(18*C(25-(10),7))%2FC(25,8)).